Authorize.net error: Invalid property identifier character: \\. Path
The whole error message is:

"code":"E00001","text":"Invalid property identifier character: \. Path 'createTransactionRequest.transactionRequest.billTo.company', line 48, position 56."

The line with the billTo.company says:
"company": "YO'S LEARNING CENTER",

The only issue that I can see there is the single quote.
When I take the json of my submission through a json validator, it says it's correct. So I'm a bit baffled.
(Any submissions without the quote are coming through fine)
I'm posting it to: https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api
with the header: "Content-Type: application/json"
What am I missing??
